# KafkaConsumer polling timeout and performance impact on the broker

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka consumer app with a polling consumption loop like this:

```
Consumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = createConsumer();
Duration pollingTimeout = Duration.ofMillis(100);

while (true) {

    // do monitoring stuff which needs to be run periodically

    for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : consumer.poll(pollingTimeout)) {
        handle(record); // this finishes within a couple of ms usually, very quick
    }
}
```

My app seems to be working fine but I'm wondering if the `pollingTimeout` here being too small has any performance impact on the broker side. Could there be any impact (like, will each poll call send a request or something to the broker and add a pressure on it?) or can I decide it purely based on how often the monitoring stuff needs to be run?

Comment: 100ms seems to be low in my opinion atleast .
To be on the safer side, maybe add some breathing room also , since other network/process delays might be there.
Also you might wanna have a look at the max.poll.records property too, which controls the number of records pulled for each poll ( all of which needs to be processed before the poll.timeout )